# How to group data and construct a new column - python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
postcode house_number  col2  col3
xxx      xxx           xxx   xxx
xxx      xxx           xxx   xxx
```

I want to group the data by `postcode` and `house_number`, if two rows have the same postcode and house_number, it means they are the same property, then I want to construct a `unique_id` for each property (in other words, for a `unique_id`, the `postcode` / `house_number` must be the same, but the value for `col2` / `col3` might be different), something like:

```
unique_id postcode house_number  col2  col3
0         111      222           xxx   xxx 
0         111      222           xxx   xxx
1         xxx      xxx           xxx   xxx
.....
```

I tried `new_df = ppd_df.groupby(['postcode','house_number']).reset_index()` but it gave me error `AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'reset_index'`, also I'm not sure how to construct the column `unique_id`. Can someone help please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) to "[n]umber each group from 0 to the number of groups - 1":

```
df['unique_id'] = df.groupby(['postcode', 'house_number']).ngroup()
```

`df`:

```
   postcode  house_number  col2  col3  unique_id
0       111           222     1     5          0
1       111           222     2     6          0
2       111           444     3     7          1
3       333           333     4     8          2
```

[`insert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) can be used to make it the first column if needed:

```
df.insert(0, 'unique_id', df.groupby(['postcode', 'house_number']).ngroup())
```

`df`:

```
   unique_id  postcode  house_number  col2  col3
0          0       111           222     1     5
1          0       111           222     2     6
2          1       111           444     3     7
3          2       333           333     4     8
```

---

*Note: `sort=False` can be used to ensure that groups are enumerated in the order in which they appear in the DataFrame:

```
df['unique_id'] = df.groupby(['postcode', 'house_number'], sort=False).ngroup()
```

Or

```
df.insert(0, 'unique_id',
          df.groupby(['postcode', 'house_number'], sort=False).ngroup())
```

Otherwise groups will be enumerated in the "order in which the groups would be seen when iterating over the groupby object, not the order they are first observed."

---

DataFrame and imports:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'postcode': [111, 111, 111, 333],
    'house_number': [222, 222, 444, 333],
    'col2': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'col3': [5, 6, 7, 8],
})
```

Comment: Hi I tried your approach, but the value for `unique_id` starts from -1 not 0

Comment: That is not possible. `ngroup` cannot generate negative numbers.

Comment: I forgot the handy ngroup that is actually fetching the grouper.group_info[0] value, thanks for the reminder ;)

Comment: Ah right, one of the columns I used to groupby contains multiple `NaN` values, I removed that column, looks like it works now

Comment: Ah very interesting. If both postcode or house_number are `NaN` groups do appear to give back -1. Very weird. I don't think that is the intended behaviour... I assume since `NaN != NaN` it can't determine how to group it.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful! Just wondering if you know how to achieve this by using Apache Beam? I've got another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68795096/use-apache-beam-to-groupby-and-construct-a-new-column-python Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry. Not an Apache guy. But glad I could help here :)

Answer (score 0):

Create tuple from `postcode` and `house_number` columns and use `pd.factorize` to get a unique identifier:

```
df['unique_id'] = \
    pd.factorize(df[['postcode', 'house_number']].apply(tuple, axis=1))[0]
```

```
>>> df
   postcode  house_number col2 col3  unique_id
0       111           222  xxx  xxx          0
1       111           333  xxx  xxx          1
2       111           222  xxx  xxx          0
3       111           222  xxx  xxx          0
4       222           444  xxx  xxx          2
```

Comment: Interesting solution, however ~3 times slower than a simple `groupby` ;)