# Use Apache beam `GroupByKey` and construct a new column - Python

Tags: python, json, csv, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

From this question: [How to group data and construct a new column - python pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68794856/how-to-group-data-and-construct-a-new-column-python-pandas/68794973#68794973), I know how to groupby multiple columns and construct a new unique id by using `pandas`, but if I want to use `Apache beam` in Python to achieve the same thing that is described in that question, how can I achieve it and then write the new data to a newline delimited JSON format file (each line is one `unique_id` with an array of objects that belong to that unique_id)?

Assuming the dataset is stored in a csv file.

I'm new to Apache beam, here's what I have now:

```
import pandas
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.dataframe.io import read_csv

with beam.Pipeline() as p:
    df = p | read_csv("example.csv", names=cols)
    agg_df = df.insert(0, 'unique_id',
          df.groupby(['postcode', 'house_number'], sort=False).ngroup())
    agg_df.to_csv('test_output')
```

This gave me an error:

```
NotImplementedError: 'ngroup' is not yet supported (BEAM-9547)
```

This is really annoying, I'm not very familiar with Apache beam, can someone help please...

(ref: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/dataframes/overview/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning consecutive integers to a set is not something that's very amenable to parallel computation. It's also not very stable. Is there any reason another identifier (e.g. the tuple `(postcode, house_number)` or its hash would not be suitable?

Comment: Hi I don't follow your question, are you asking why I need to construct another identifier?

Comment: Yes, or why this identifier can't be an (injective) function of postcode and house_number.

Comment: The value for the identifier doesn't matter, it's only used to identify the same property.

Comment: In that case, simply concatenate the postcode and house number and use that as an identifier (e.g. `df['unique_id'] = df['postcode'] + '-' + df['house_number ']`)