# Convert (csv) data to newline delimited JSON format grouping them based on the row using Apache Beam

Tags: python, json, group-by, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have a dataset of properties sold/bought. Each row of the data is a unique property transaction, if a property has been bought/sold multiple times in the time-series the data covers, there will be multiple rows for the same property, one per unique transaction.

I would like to convert the data to newline delimited JSON format grouping the transactions by property with the output having a single JSON object per property and with each property object containing an array of transaction objects for the property.

For this data transformation I want to use Apache Beam (I'm assuming the **GroupByKey** feature) but I'm quite new to it so I'm unsure how to implement this. Since the data does not contain a unique property ID, I would also need to construct an appropriate unique property ID from the property details.

I'm fairly new to data pipeline design and transformations so I would really appreciate some advice with examples on how I would resolve this.

[Here is an image of what the data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVxOn.png)

I hope this makes sense! Thanks a lot!

Update: I'm using this code

```
    import apache_beam as beam
    from apache_beam.dataframe.io import read_csv
    
    with beam.Pipeline() as p:
        df = p | read_csv("example.csv")
        agg_df = df.insert(0, 'unique_id',
              df.groupby(['postcode', 'house_number'], sort=False).ngroup())
        agg_df.to_csv('test_output')
```

But I get this error.

NotImplementedError: 'ngroup' is not implemented yet.

Example Data:

[How to group data and construct a new column - python pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68794856/how-to-group-data-and-construct-a-new-column-python-pandas/68794973#68794973)

This post talks about a similar issue  but they use pandas to resolve it and I want to construct it using Apache Beam.

Comment: Use `defaultdict(list)` to create a dictionary that you can append to each nested list with.

Comment: Have you a code snippet to share with us or please can you give a mock for input and expected data and I could maybe propose you a solution with `Beam` pipeline ?  GroupByKey can be a good choice.

Comment: Hey @MazlumTosun I have updated my post with a code snippet

Comment: Ok thanks, can you also give us a mock for inputs and expected data please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use defaultdict to create dictionary.

Example:

```
property_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for row in csv_reader:
        property_dict[row['property_id']].append(row)
```