# Use Apache Beam to construct new column with unique ID

Tags: python, json, csv, apache-beam

I'm quite new to Apache Beam and I'm trying to create a new column at index 0 that uses groupbykey on multiple columns and construct a new unique id. How am I able to achieve this?

Also I want to write the new data to a newline delimited JSON format file (where each line is one unique_id with an array of objects that belong to that unique_id.

I've currently written:

```
import apache_beam as beam

pipe = beam.Pipeline()

id = (pipe
            |beam.io.ReadFromText('data.csv')
            |beam.Map(lambda x:x.split(","))
            |beam.Map(print))
```

Which basically converts each row into a list of strings.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68794856/how-to-group-data-and-construct-a-new-column-python-pandas/68794973#68794973) has the sample data input and the solutions use pandas to do so but how do I achieve the same in the pipeline using Beam?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CombinePerKey like this?

```
import apache_beam as beam

p = beam.Pipeline()

test = (
    p
    | beam.Create([(0, "ttt"), (0, "ttt1"), (0, "ttt2"), (1, "xxx"), (1, "xxx2"), (2, "yyy")])
    | beam.CombinePerKey(lambda v: ",".join(v))
    | beam.Map(print)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Could you please tell me how I would implement this on an existing csv PCollection? @XQ Hu

Comment: Assuming t.txt has the data like these:

```
0, "ttt"
0, "ttt1"
0, "ttt2"
1, "xxx"
1, "xxx2"
2, "yyy"
```

I could do this:

```
import apache_beam as beam

p = beam.Pipeline()

test = (
    p
    | beam.io.ReadFromText("t.txt")
    | beam.Map(lambda x: x.split(","))
    | beam.CombinePerKey(lambda v: ",".join(v))
    | beam.Map(print)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it important to you to have the unique IDs be integers from 0 to n_groups like in your linked example?

If not, then I don't think there's any need to use a grouping operation here. Consider the following:

```
import apache_beam as beam

def make_unique_id(row):
  """
  Example function for extracting a unique ID from the row.

  You could wrap the value in uuid.UUID to make a more standard format for the ID.
  """
  return ",".join([row[0], row[1]])

pipe = beam.Pipeline()

id = (pipe
            | beam.io.ReadFromText('data.csv')
            | beam.Map(lambda x: x.split(","))
            | beam.Map(lambda x: [make_unique_id(x)] + x)
            | beam.Map(print))
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. Yeah, I want the unique ID's to be integers like the one showed in the post. Would you be able to suggest a different way to achieve that? Thanks.